# img src: display 1 picture from a pool of photos depending on url

Tags: image, src

if i have a pool of images and want to only display one of them depending on the url of the site, what is the best way to achieve this?

i have tried using basic html code in the body.php file:

```
<img src="image-pool.php">
```

and image-pool.php:

```
<?
header ('content-type: image/jpg'); 
readfile($img);

switch($url)
{
 case 'page1.php':
  echo '<img src="image1.jpg">';
  break;
 case 'page2.php':
  echo '<img src="image2.jpg">';
  break;
 case 'page3.php':
  echo '<img src="image3.jpg">';
  break;
 default:
  echo '<img src="image1.jpg">';
  break;
}; 
?>
```

but images arent showing up. If this logic does work (with some editing of the above codes), could it be rewritten so that i can inject the php code within the brackets of img src="" so i can combine the php code within the same file? or is there a simpler way to achieve what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put your case into body.php?

image-pool.php should return image content (raw bytes), and not html.